# How to animate a 3D model identical to the poses of a source human using PoseNet?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, pose-estimation

We are developing an pose estimation system that animate a 3D model in the screen based on the pose of the human

I want 3D rendering like this :: 
[image: 3D rendering]

I searched in their offical github repo but only 2D code is there

A 3D implementation is available in github but it is very basic

Does PoseNet supports 3D pose estimation ?

Please guide me

Comment: Found this repo: https://github.com/mishig25/3d-posenet, but I haven't tried yet :)

Comment: @GoonNguyen any luck with this yet? I can only get the head to match motion.